How to check if I'm in a Laravel HTTP Request context?
I need to know if I'm in an HTTP request context or not where my code is currently running.
Examples of being in an HTTP request context:

An actual HTTP request running in fpm-fpm.
A test request being processed while running a test (the test part is not in HTTP request context, but the execution of the request calls are).
An actual HTTP request being processed in Octane.
An actual HTTP request being processed using the built-in PHP server.

I can't just do PHP_SAPI !== 'cli', because that would fail for examples 2-4.
It's fine for me if I would need to call any facades.

In Laravel you can do !app()->runningInConsole() which would pass 4 when using php artisan serve
The only one that wont work would be 2 because Laravel doesn't keep track when its running "http context code".
You can add a middleware that keeps track but its probably not recommended to couple your code to the request anyway...

class HttpContextMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        HttpContext::start();

        $response = $next($request);

        HttpContext::stop();

        return $response;
    }
}

Note: This middleware is not tested and will most probably not work with octane unless you implement HttpContext to store the flag on request() object
What is an example code that depends on being in http?
